# Python nested loop speed issues

Tags: python, for-loop

I am currently working on a program to test for ideal angle-values to construct something. Now I'm stuck at a nested-for-loop which I'm going to attach below. While idealy it would count each 'a' to 9000, it already takes almost forever if values are set like below. Is there a way to speed up this nested loop? Or can i somehow assign more ressources to python?

```
for a1 in  xrange(15, 91):
    for a2 in xrange(15, 91):
        for a3 in xrange(15, 91):
            for a4 in xrange(15, 91):
                for a5 in xrange(15, 91):
                    for ite in xrange(1, 1000):
                        ok = mathmatvec(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, ite) 
                        if ok == 1:
                                v[0] = a1
                                v[1] = a2
                                .
                                .
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to check all `76 * 76 * 76 * 76 * 76 * 999` = `2532989850624` = **2.5 trillion** combinations? Even if operation to perform would be nothing (replace last for statement body with "pass") it'll still take "almost forever".

Comment: what does mathmatvec() do? time complexity for that function?

Comment: it calculates multiple vector and matrix multiplications. It doesn't take a notable time if just used once on its own. for a little more details see my response to Rory Daulton

Comment: make it a function an add `@numba.jit` before it

Comment: If you look for parameters in high dimensions, you might want to use a random search or even a minimization over a loss criterion

Answer (score 1):

The [*itertools.product()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) function will greatly speed the nested for-loops.

That said, the running time will likely be dominated by the total number of calls to *mathmatvec()*.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to convert `for` loops into `while` loops, should be faster as the latter does not create any iterators. So instead of:

```
for a1 in xrange(15, 91):
```

write:

```
a1 = 15
while a1 < 91:
    ...
    a1 += 1
```

Or try to use [PyPy](http://pypy.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Use a different algorithm.

As it is now, you execute the innermost loop 999*(76**5) == 2,532,989,850,624 times. This is probably too many, unless the innermost loop calculations are trivial.

You say you want "to test for ideal angle-values to construct something." If you can formalize what "ideal" means, you can use an optimization algorithm to zero in on what you want. If you give us more details on what you are searching for, we may be able to tell you about a better Python routine or algorithm.

---

If I understand you correctly, `mathmatvec()` takes only values 0 and 1, and you want to find values of `a1,a2,a3,a4` for `15 <= a1 <= 90` etc. and `ite` for `1 <= ite <= 999` that make `mathmatvec(a1, a2, a3, a4, ite)` equal to 1 and where `ite` is as small as possible.

You can make this a multidimensional minimization problem by using the function

```
def func(a1, a2, a3, a4, ite):
    return ite - 1000 * mathmatvec(a1, a2, a3, a4, ite)
```

Then `func()` returns a positive number for `mathmatvec() == 0` and a negative one for `mathmatvec() == 1`, and the negative values are minimized when `ite` is minimized.

Depending on how "smooth" your function `mathmatvec()` is, how connected it is, and its fitness landscape, one of the minimization routines in [scipy.optimize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) may solve your problem well enough. The [scipy.optimize.differential_evolution() function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html#scipy.optimize.differential_evolution) looks particularly interesting.

Comment: while i can't put the formula in mathmatvec into trivial terms, it tests for which 5 angles, a minimal ite can be reached (ite value is *0.0001 in the formula) so my guess was to check each possible angle combination (range 15 to 90 degrees) if a minimal valid (result of the function) value for ite can be found.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean about "ite." But are you looking for the values of variables a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, ite that give you the smallest "valid" result of the function mathmatvec()? If so, what kind of values are returned and with what range? What is an "invalid" function result? It now sounds like you want a multi-dimensional minimizer: more detail will confirm or deny.

Comment: **a1-5** and **ite** are part of one big formula which must result in a value within a certain range. if it does, the result is "valid" and i return **1**, otherwise **0**. However, the final result which I need, is a minimal **ite** for any constellation of **a1-5**. So whenever all conditions are met AND the **ite** is smaller then what any constellation so far resulted in, i save all current values.